# pandas slicing columns if all elements of the column are negative

Tags: python, pandas

I did it this way but I feel like it could be simpler.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,1,1,1], 'B':[-1,-1,-1,-1], 'C':[-1,-1,-1,-1], 'D':[-1,-1,-1,-1], 'E':[1,1,1,1]})
print df

msk= []
for i,k in enumerate(df.columns.tolist()):
    if (df.iloc[:,i]<0).all(0):
        msk.append(k)

df[msk]
print df[msk]
```

Comment: provide some I/O example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.all` and pass `axis=0`:

```
In [14]:

df[df.columns[np.all(df<0, axis=0)]]
Out[14]:
   B  C  D
0 -1 -1 -1
1 -1 -1 -1
2 -1 -1 -1
3 -1 -1 -1
```

**Timings**

```
In [18]:

%%timeit
msk= []
for i,k in enumerate(df.columns.tolist()):
    if (df.iloc[:,i]<0).all(0):
        msk.append(k)

df[msk]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.78 ms per loop
In [19]:

%timeit df[df.columns[np.all(df < 0, axis=0)]]

1000 loops, best of 3: 661 µs per loop
```

**Update**

@Aerofoil's answer is in fact the slowest here, it probably scales better than your's but I doubt it'll faster than the numpy method

```
In [25]:

%timeit df[(df<0)].dropna(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.11 ms per loop
```

**Further update**

If we compare the performance on a 400,000 row df then we see the following:

your method:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 42.2 ms per loop
```

@Aerofoil's method:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 124 ms per loop
```

numpy method using `np.all`:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 9.47 ms per loop
```

So we see that the numpy method scales much better as it is vectorised

Comment: In[189]: %timeit df[(df<0)].dropna(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.09 ms per loop
In[190]: %timeit df[df.columns[np.all(df < 0, axis=0)]]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.25 ms per loop

Comment: thanks for showing this solution as well, it's pretty damn quick

Comment: what explains this huge timing difference if possible in a few words ?

Comment: the numpy method is vectorised, it's looking at the entire array, in fact your method is also vectorised but it's looping over all the columns whilst the numpy method will look at the entire df, I don't know why aerofoil's method is so much slower other than it's generating a boolean index for the df and then it's dropping `NaN` values so it's performing more work and probably copying data around

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help:

```
>>> from pandas import *
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> L = [[1,2,-1], [-5,6,-3], [-1,-2,-7]]

>>> df = DataFrame(L)
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  1  2 -1
1 -5  6 -3
2 -1 -2 -7

>>> df1 = df[(df<0)].dropna(axis=1)
>>> df1
   2
0 -1
1 -3
2 -7
```